# How to position the timestamp with tikzpicture but not change the position of texts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am using tikzpicture to put a timestamp in my article, and everthing seems to be good. However, once I compile the tikzpicture, the text would sink and I don't expect that such a blank at the beginning. How can I fix it or using an alternative rather than tikzpicture?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[long]{datetime}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{setspace}

\title{\textbf{Title}}
\author{\textbf{Name:} Alan}
\date{\textbf{Date of Meeting:} \formatdate{18}{2}{2021}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0.5cm] at (current page.north east)
    {\fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont Latest edited at \currenttime \ on \today};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{framed}
    \noindent
    \textbf{ABC:} abcs.
\end{framed}

\section{11}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

You may see the spacing between the date and the frame is different because of the tikzpicture.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the simplest solution is to put the `tikzpicture` environment at the end of `\maketitle`. Put the code below in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\maketitle}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
 \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0.5cm] at (current page.north east)
 {\fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont Latest edited at \currenttime \ on \today};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}{}{}
```